# How do I skip a plug for an specific page

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am building a Phoenix app with authentication. In my router I have something like:

```
pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug MyApp.Plugs.Authenticate
end

scope "/", MyApp do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", HomeController, :show
    get "/login", SessionsController, :login
    get "/matches", MatchesController, :index
end
```

I want to skip the Authenticate plug for /login, can I do this in the router or do I have to do this in the Plug itself?

Plugs.Authenticate looks like:

```
def call(conn, _) do
    case Authenticator.find_user(conn) do
        {:ok, user} ->
            assign(conn, :user, user)
        :error ->
            conn
                |> redirect(to: "/login")
                |> halt
    end
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to do this is to define a separate pipeline:

```
pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
end

pipeline :auth do
    plug MyApp.Plugs.Authenticate
end

scope "/", MyApp do
    pipe_through [:browser, :auth]

    get "/", HomeController, :show
    get "/matches", MatchesController, :index
end

scope "/", MyApp do
    pipe_through :browser

    get "/login", SessionsController, :login
end
```

There are a couple things to note here.

1) The pipelines are being chained in the example where authentication is required.

2) You can use the same scope multiple times as long as the actual route is distinct this is because the routes above compile roughly to:

```
defmodule MyRouter do
  def match(conn, :get,    ["/"])
  def match(conn, :get,    ["/matches"])
  def match(conn, :get,    ["/login"])
end
```

You can read more about how the macros in Phoenix routing work towards the end of the slides at http://www.chrismccord.com/blog/2014/03/13/write-less-do-more-and-have-fun-with-elixir-macros/